# How can i get the image matrix co ordinates in android?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I am developing an application where is included crop functionality and in this I'm blocked at below scenario.

***The scenario***:

Crop overlay is not circulating the whole image when we apply straightening to the image if we change the crop overlay, ratio also is not working.

I got the code from google but it is related to matrix, I have tried using matrix, but here I need to find the coordinates(edges) of matrix to move the overlay.

How to find it? If anyone has any idea please help me...

I added the image to explain the problem
[image]

Thanks in advance..
I am using the below code but I didn't get the exact coordinates of the matrix

```
RectF r = new RectF(); 
 mymatrix.mapRect(r);
 Rect rect = 
 new Rect((int)r.left,int)r.top,int)r.right+width,int)r.bottom+height);
```

Comment: You should not use `mapRect` if you are applying rotation on your matrix. My advice is to figure out the 4 initial points representing each rectangle edge (the image itself) and use `mapPoints` instead.

Comment: thanks for reply is there any sample code

Answer (score 7):

You should not use `mapRect` if you are applying rotation on your matrix. My advice is to figure out the 4 initial points representing each rectangle edge (the image itself) and use `mapPoints` instead.

Lets say you have an image 200px wide and 200px tall with its top left corner positioned at origin (0,0).

If you rotate this image from its center (100,100) 45 degrees and then scale it 200% from its center we will have the following scenario:

```
    //original image coords
    float[] points = {
            0f, 0f, //left, top
            200f, 0f, //right, top
            200f, 200f, //right, bottom
            0f, 200f//left, bottom
    };

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    //rotate 45 degrees from image center
    matrix.postRotate(45f, 100f, 100f);
    //scale 200% from center
    matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, 100f, 100f);

    //get the new edges coords
    matrix.mapPoints(points);
```

After calling `matrix.mapPoints(points)` the points array will have the updated coords. This means `points[0], points[1]` will have the new left top image coord and so on.

The even indices represents the abscissas and the odd indices represents the ordinates on the `points` array.

Comment: Thanks for reply how to convert the points to Rect values?bcoz,here i want to fix the boundaries to the overlay to move the throughout matrix bitmap

Comment: You have to keep in mind that `Rect` class alone will not represent the blue rect on the image you posted. That been said, what do you mean by "to fix the boundaries to the overlay to move the throughout matrix bitmap"? I could not understand correctly.

Comment: sorry,i want to move the overlay throughout the matrix(blueborder)

Comment: Have you played with the code above? If you use drawing primitives to draw the points after calling `mapPoints` it may help you. You were asking to the image coords, and that is what the code do. Beyond that I'm afraid I can not help you further because I could not yet understand the "move the overlay throughout the matrix(blueborder)" part.

Comment: i think overlay is nothing but the rect(yellow border) inside the bitmap and he want to move throughout the image is it right ashok?